# Python - detection of empty URLs - using string manipulation

Tags: python, string, url

I need to parse files and detect empty URLS
these are the scenarios:

```
href = ''(ideally)
href     = '    '
```

Both cases, although there are spaces in the second, work the same. What i have done is get all the text in the file into a string variable `'searchstring'`.i have used 
`searchstring.find('href = '')` not equal to -1 for the former case above , but in case of varying spaces like in the second, am not sure what i need to do to ensure i catch those scenarios too...
Initially i thought of  using index to caputure the index , and
 then traverse , but it seems like a laborious solution to me....
It may seem silly, but am new to python, just started learning since yesterday. Could anyone share some insight

thanks a lot in advance,
Philip

Answer (score 1):

I'd start by installing [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) ... then I'd just loop over your files and let it do the parsing for you.

From there you could do something like:

```
## import re ## Don't actually need a regex here:

for link in soup.find_all('a'):
    if not link.get('href').strip():
        print link, "... is empty or spacey"
    ## elif re.search(r'^\s*$',link.get('href')):
        ## print link, "... is spacey"
```

Comment: Actually inspectorG4dget's post reminds me that you could simplify this using .strip() as noted above (after my next edit)

Answer (score 0):

check the length (or better yet, the `bool`) of `href.strip()`:

```
In [47]: href = ''

In [48]: len(href.strip())
Out[48]: 0

In [49]: bool(href.strip())
Out[49]: False

In [50]: href = '    '

In [51]: len(href.strip())
Out[51]: 0

In [52]: bool(href.strip())
Out[52]: False
```

Comment: Sounds good, also there is another pattern of string i need to watch out for i.e. window.open .....foreg window.open('http://www.google.com');

Comment: Here i need to detect if window.open is empty or not , are there any built in functions for this one?

Comment: I don't know what `window.open` returns, so I don't know how to check whether it is empty

Answer (score 0):

why don't you strip href

```
href = href.strip()
```

Or

```
if href.strip():
    print "not empty"
else:
    print "empty"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `re`. You'd better read the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html).

```
>>> import re
>>> s='href=""adjfweofhref="   "'
>>> pattern = re.compile(r'href=[\"\']\s*[\"\']')
>>> pattern.findall(s)
['href=""', 'href="   "']
>>>
```